# Plot gridded map

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame with `LON`, `LAT` and `SST` where the `SST` value is the mean of the corresponding cell. I would like to plot the `SST` value for every `LON`,`LAT` point but when using `ggplot`

```
graph <- ggplot(aes(x = df$lon, y = df$lat), data = df) + geom_tile(aes(fill = df$moav)) 
print(graph)
```

I get an empty graph. Where am I doing wrong? Is `ggplot` the correct function to use?

Man thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify `df$` for the aesthetics

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = lon, y = lat)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = moav))
```

Answer (score 0):

If `SST` is the value you wish to plot in `geom_tile`, you're specifying the wrong value (`moav`)

```
 ggplot(data = df,
        aes(x = lon, y = lat) +

 geom_tile( aes(fill = sst) )
```

Should work, that assumes that `SST` is something that `geom_tile` can understand (e.g., numeric or integer).